# What is "Data availability problem" in Plasma?

Tags: rollups, plasma

> What differentiates Rollup from Plasma is that it solves Plasma’s huge
> problem — data availability

Can someone please describe the "data availability" problem in Plasma?
Ok, in Plasma the only data on-chain is the Merkle Root.
But users can always "exit" the chain by providing the Merkle proof that they own assets and by waiting for N days. Merkle proof is validated by smart contract.

**So what data can become unavailable?** Even if the Operator/Sequencer is switched off or absent...